# The filter() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
const nums = [0,10,20,30,40,50];
nums.filter( function(num) {
    return num > 20;
})
```

please breakdown the code in a simple way I'm a newbiew :)
help me guys to understand this more clearly.

How can we display the filtered value here? how to display the returned values?

I understood the other code like

```
function canVote(age)
{
    return age>=18;
}
function func(){
    var filtered = [22,34,12,23,56,12,11,1].filter(canVote);
    console.log(filtered);
}
func();
```

but I am not being able to understand the return type code

Comment: ”Get me numbers that are bigger than 20”

Comment: filter returns a new array matching the conditions you have set in this case age>=20

Comment: If you want to display the returned values, you have to assign the result of filtering the array to a variable (like in your second example). Then you have something that you can display. (Or, you can just put the whole nums.filter(...) thing in your console.log() call.)

Comment: What is unclear about the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your talking about is creating the function inside the filter and the return statement made.

When a return statement is made it is actually the condition. In this case checking if the current number is above 20. If so then add it to the array that will be created by the filter

My prefrence for filter functions is using an arrow function like so

```
let arr = [0, 19, 21, 22]
let filterd = arr.filter(num => num > 20); // for one param you dont need () around parameters
let filterd2 = arr.filter((num, index) => {
  if (num < 20) {
    return [num, index]
  }
};

console.log(filterd)// logs "[21, 22]"
console.log(filterd2)// logs "[[0, 0][19, 1]]"
```